# a instanceof b returns false even though b is in a's prototype chain

Tags: javascript, antlr4, instanceof

Yet another `instanceof` question.
I'm using some autogenerated code from an antlr4 parser. The parser works fine, I plugged it together withe ace, syntax highlighting works,... so far so good. But now a very strange thing happens. I wrote my own `parserTreeListener`, which fails because of a`instanceof` call returning the wrong result.

Breaking the problem down to a small program worked. But like magic, everything is going fine there even though it uses the same code (Parser, Lexer, Listener,...)

Not strange enough, debugging the issue in chrome devtools, shows me that the objects `t` prototyping chain (__proto__) indeed is an instance of `TerminalNode` but calling `t instanceof TerminalNode` nevertheless returns `false`.
[image: here it works]
[image: here it doesn't]

Unfortunately I cannot publish the code of the main project, where it fails (at least not yet). Maybe someone has an idea why and when such issues could arise.

some possible explanations (even though I doubt)

- script is loaded twice and TerminalNode does not equal proto's TerminalNode
- clash with the same library loaded in a worker thread

At this piece of code in antlr4 it fails:

```
ParseTreeWalker.prototype.walk = function(listener, t) {
var errorNode = t instanceof ErrorNode ||
        (t.isErrorNode !== undefined && t.isErrorNode());
if (errorNode) {
    listener.visitErrorNode(t);
} else if (t instanceof TerminalNode) { /*here t fails on first TerminalNode*/
    listener.visitTerminal(t);
} else {
    this.enterRule(listener, t);
    for (var i = 0; i < t.getChildCount(); i++) {
        var child = t.getChild(i);
        this.walk(listener, child);
    }
    this.exitRule(listener, t);
}
};
```

---

Some debugging info

both scripts return the same at the break point when I type:

```
$ var obj = t; while(obj) console.log(obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
TerminalNode {}
ParseTree {}
SyntaxTree {}
Tree {}
Object {}
Object {}
```

Comment: What does `t.prototype === TerminalNode.prototype` say?

Comment: `instanceof` is not the same as `.isPrototypeOf`! Edit: OK, only your question title is confusing.

Comment: `false` in both cases: `t instanceof TerminalNode
true
t.prototype === TerminalNode.prototype
false` even at the example where it works, which is ok because `t` is an instance of `TerminalNodeImpl`

Comment: Did you find the answer to this problem?

Comment: @Nayan As stated in the answer below... The script was loaded multiple times, overriding the original definitions, thus leading to this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I do not have an explanation, how such strange behavior can happen. A double included script was the root cause of the error. As I use Polymer and Webcomponents, multiple components include the same script.

By moving the particular `<script ..>` Tag out of the components into the main document, those problems did not occur any more.

Maybe there is still someone who has a clue, why this can lead to such errors?

Comment: Well if the script is executed multiple times, there are multiple classes that look alike (same name, same members) etc but are not the same. An instance of the first class, created before `TerminalNode` was overwritten by the second execution, is not an instance of the second class.

Comment: I kinda expected that you had checked for this before asking the question as you've already mentioned this as a possible cause…

Comment: @Bergi I indeed checked it, but the include was kinda hidden (means it wasn't obvious). I even uncommented one importScript-Statement in a worker-thread using the same library - but of course, this wasn't the problem as worker-threads anyway are sandboxed from the other environment. I usually all the times solve the problems before having to ask here, but this seemed so weird to me, that I thought it could be helpful for others facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

`a instanceof b` checks if `a` inherits from `b.prototype`, not from `b`.

If you want to test whether `b` itself appears in the prototypical chain of `a`, you can use

```
b.isPrototypeOf(a);
```

Some examples:

```
[] instanceof Array;                           // true
Array.isPrototypeOf([]);                       // false
Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array;           // false

[] instanceof Array.prototype;                 // TypeError
Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf([]);             // true
Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array.prototype; // true
```

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(t)`
returns `TerminalNode {}`
`TerminalNode.isPrototypeOf(t)`
returns `false`
`t instanceof TerminalNode`
should return `true` ! `TerminalNode.prototype.isPrototypeOf(t)`
returns `false` in the failing script and `true` at the one that works. Still no answer to the problem

Comment: @SeDav Try something like `var obj = t; while(obj) console.log(obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));`, and you will see all the prototypical chain.

Comment: I did it and added it to the question

Comment: it seems to be a weird concurrency problem, disabling the ace syntax highlighting (which is accessing the same library) then everything works...strange...I will further examine the problem. maybe it has to do  with the UMD browserify approach (I browserified the antlr4 lib + parsers)